# Python list of tuples, need to unpack and clean up

Tags: python, python-2.7

Assume you have a list such as

`x = [('Edgar',), ('Robert',)]`

What would be the most efficient way to get to just the strings `'Edgar'` and `'Robert'`?

Don't really want x[0][0], for example.

Comment: The most efficient way would depend on what you plan to do with them afterwards. For example, there's no point building a new list, if you're just going to iterate that list afterwards. If that's the case, it's more efficient to just do something like: `for (i,) in x: do_something_with(i)`.

Comment: I need to send this string to another function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy solution, and the fastest in most cases.

```
[item[0] for item in x]
#or
[item for (item,) in x]
```

Alternatively if you need a functional interface to index access (but slightly slower):

```
from operator import itemgetter

zero_index = itemgetter(0)

print map(zero_index, x)
```

Finally, if your sequence is too small to fit in memory, you can do this iteratively. This is much slower on collections but uses only one item's worth of memory.

```
from itertools import chain

x = [('Edgar',), ('Robert',)]

# list is to materialize the entire sequence.
# Normally you would use this in a for loop with no `list()` call.
print list(chain.from_iterable(x))
```

But if all you are going to do is iterate anyway, you can also just use tuple unpacking:

```
for (item,) in x:
    myfunc(item)
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated from a fellow philosophy undergrad kid.

Comment: Why do you say `itemgetter` version is faster?

Comment: Because I am crazy. I think it used to be faster, but just tested on CPython 2.7 and it's not. Amending answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty straightforward with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
x = [('Edgar',), ('Robert',)]
y = [s for t in x for s in t]
```

This does the same thing as `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x))` and is equivalent in behavior to the following code:

```
y = []
for t in x:
    for s in t:
        y.append(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I need to send this string to another function.

If your intention is just to call a function for each string in the list, then there's no need to build a new list, just do...

```
def my_function(s):
    # do the thing with 's'

x = [('Edgar',), ('Robert',)]

for (item,) in x:
    my_function(item)
```

...or if you're prepared to sacrifice readability for performance, I suspect it's quickest to do...

```
def my_function(t):
    s = t[0]        
    # do the thing with 's'
    return None

x = [('Edgar',), ('Robert',)]
filter(my_function, x)
```

Both `map()` and `filter()` will do the iteration in C, rather than Python bytecode, but `map()` will need to build a list of values the same length of the input list, whereas `filter()` will only build an empty list, as long as `my_function()` returns a 'falsish' value.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
>>> [name for name, in x]
['Edgar', 'Robert']
```

Note the placement of the comma, which unpacks the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> y = map(itemgetter(0), x)
>>> y
['Edgar', 'Robert']
>>> y[0]
'Edgar'
>>> y[1]
'Robert'
```